# Combobox for single data, but multiple representations

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am not sure combobox would be the best vehicle for tackling this problem, but visually it is appealing.

Consider such data as angle -- I could enter its value in radians (single editbox) or in form of degree, minute, second, millisecond (4 editboxes) -- there are other representations, but those two will suffice here. For now I have combobox with mode entries "radians", "DMS" changing mode shows/hides appropriate control.

This approach has two flaws -- it takes a bit more space (for extra combobox with modes), and since each control is different is size everything on right of it moves.

So I am thinking about more direct approach, instead selecting mode, which in turns switches visibility of given control, would it be possible to put each control inside combobox, and combobox would then select that control. The target data would be exactly the same for each row (angle), but each row would have different control, because each row would mean different representation.

Is doable with combobox or am I banging at the wrong door? If combobox is suitable for this task, how to do it?

Comment: It is absolutely possible. You will have to put in some effort yourself, before somebody helps you with it.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, true, but it was not "effort" factor, but going back to basics :-) Anyway, thank you for reassuring me I am on the right track.

Comment: This helped me a lot: http://www.eidias.com/Blog/2012/2/20/customizing-wpf-combo-box-style

Answer (score 0):

I was so focused on data binding at the combobox level that I didn't notice that the solution uses the basics of combobox.

So first, for the moment forget about combobox binding to anything -- simply per each row define `ComboBoxItem` and put any control you like. In effect you will get multiple controls for the same data.

At this point the only missing part is selecting the mode. Since I no longer rely on manually switching visibility of the controls (combobox does it automatically) then I can bind to `SelectedIndex` and convert it only fly back and forth to mode.

Please note combobox is not bound per se to the actual data (angle in this case).